# App suddenly crashes when run on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app runs great in the simulator, and has been working great on device as well. Today I am trying to install on device and the app crashes. It still works in the simulator. I am getting no debug errors:

```
[Session started at 2010-07-19 10:35:01 -0700.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1470) (Thu May 27 05:54:06 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys002
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-228-34
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 856.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 856.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
```

How can I diagnose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to close the simulator, and do a clean, and then a build and run. also might help to delete the app completely off the device.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the crash log from the device? If not, the device will store a log of all the crashes and you can get it from that.

http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign it with a development certificate/provisioning profile (this should be the default in the build settings) and entitlements with `<key>get-task-allow</key><true/>` (this should also be the default).

Does it run at all from the home screen?

Comment: Does not run from the home screen. I have signed it with my certificate, and have been for the past month. When I switch to my development certificate I get the error: Couldn't register com.myApp.debug with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal: “SIGABRT”.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator for the 'Couldn't register com.myApp.debug with the bootstrap server' error.