# Bootstrap Server Error in Xcode IPHONE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, osx-snow-leopard

I get the error below many times and this error makes it impossible to run my application unless I restart the whole Mac.

This is not caused due to changes in code.

**ERROR :**

**Couldn't register com.yourcompany. with the bootstrap server.Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.**

What could be wrong?

Please give your suggestions, they are most welcome.

Comment: Well, let go of the shift key. :-)      Sorry, could not resist.

Comment: Another thing, do you see this error on the iPhone, or on the Mac?

Comment: Sorry Guys i have edited it now please reply. Sorry didnt know that CAPS is shouting.

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant : i get this error in MAC

Comment: Still happens with Xcode 4.3.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can check this link. This may solve your problem.
[Couldn't register with the bootstrap Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442)

For me it has worked when I have killed the Xcode and Simulator Apps using Activity Monitor and then restarting those apps.

You can read these following threads:
[iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10416765

Comment: i tried it but doesnt work. thanks and if u get the solution please tell.Thanks

Comment: Better restart your machine and try.

Comment: I tried but everytime restarting the machine is too inconvinient so i was searching for some better solution.  Thanks Anyways

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that option.

Comment: it didnt work out. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem on my device while tethered and debugging. I had to restart my phone(iPhone 4). It makes sense based on the problems with the simulators...

Comment: You are right. For the device try deleting the installed app from the device and then re-installing it. This should work. Hope this helps you. Thanks for sharing your experience :]

Comment: Yep, ran into this myself.  Deleting the app had no effect.  The only fix was to restart the device.

Comment: I tried many of the suggestions like shutting down processies from activity monitor, cleaning targets, ... . For me only restarting my iPad 1 worked (w/o removing any app).

Answer (score 2):

(I can't leave a comment, apologies). I was getting this error running iOS 4.3.1 on iPad. I was compiling on the iPad itself, not running in the simulator. I tried everything - clean then rebuild, restarting XCode, deleting the app on iPad, running through the simulator then trying the iPad again.

What worked for me was deleting the app on my iPad, then XCode -> Product -> Clean, then rebooting the iPad (hold power button to switch off, then switch back on), then XCode -> Product Run. I don't know if all those steps are necessary, but I do know they worked! Thanks to tapdancemobile for the suggestion to restart iPad, just as you'd restart the simulator :)

Comment: Another observation - the problem seems to occur when running an app then pressing the HOME button (on device itself or in simulator) to reach springboard then deleting the app (holding app launcher icon, pressing cross). Don't do this - instead press STOP button (square symbol) in XCode, this seems to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've had little luck with recovering from this problem once it happens.  Killing processes rarely seems to succeed with this.  I can tell you how I avoid it though: don't quit the simulator while your app is still running in the debugger.

I develop on a MacBook and to save battery I would often quit the simulator while debugging.  Something gets munged up though and sometimes causes the app's process to get detached or hung or something to the point that XCode can no longer control it.  After that this error begins appearing.

Always stop your app in XCode before quitting from the simulator and the problem won't happen.

I'm not sure what situation leads to it happening when debugging on the device directly.  Maybe quitting the app by forcing it closed from Springboard?  Or possibly disconnecting the cable while still debugging /shrug

Comment: +1..Thanks..!! Even I have observed the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

```
1)  Delete app from device.
2)  you need to restart your device iPhone/iPad
3)  Also restart your Xcode.
4)  Clean your source code  in Xcode and run again
```

Boom your error goes !!

Answer (score 1):

I had my app working perfectly fine in the simulator but was shouting that error when I deployed on `iPad (iOS 5)` . My Solution :

1. Clean all targets and deploy .

If it still doesn't work :

1. Remove the app from simulator/iPad/iPhone . You may restart your
   ipad and Mac .
2. Clean all targets and try to run again.

Answer (score 1):

Try following things one by one:

1. Delete the app from iphone. (or simulator).
2. Restart your iphone.  (or simulator).
3. **If you are on iphone/ipad/ipod, have you installed any other app with the same code-signing certificate? If yes delete that too, and restart your phone.**
4. Not solved yet? Strange!! Try quitting xcode and restarting system.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned all targets, deleted my app from the simulator, and restarted my computer. Then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

i tried to solve many time. but no Result. Then i start reading Apple sdk doc and get Answer like that.

Just run this command in terminal

**launchctl list|grep UIKitApplication|awk '{print $3}'|xargs launchctl remove**

And Restart your Xcode. Problem is solve.