# Bootstrap server error when running app on Device in Xcode4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

```
Couldn't register taxsmart.MapTest with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger
```

I get this Error when I try to install my app on my Device.

I already tried restarting Mac and device.

Also tried cleaning the app and re-building. But did not work for me.

Also I tried refering to this link but didn't help me.

[Bootstrap Server Error in Xcode IPHONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905718/bootstrap-server-error-in-xcode-iphone)

What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted my Mac and my device and it worked.

Comment: Restarting the mac is not a good solution if you have this issue every 30 minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention specifically, so I'll ask: Have you tried manually deleting the application from the device? Tap and hold its icon. When they begin to wiggle, hit the x in the upper-left of the icon and confirm deletion.