# Couldn't register com.XXXXX.deviceapp with the bootstrap server

Tags: iphone, bootstrapping

I am getting this error while running in device please do need full help to solve this;

> Couldn't register com.XXXXX.deviceapp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Comment: @chown: Not a duplicate. That question is about running in the Simulator; this one is about running on an actual device.

Answer (score 78):

I have had this happen where I needed to restart the phone before error would go away.

Deleteing the app, restarting Xcode, clean build, didn't do anything.  I shut the phone down and bought it back up and the error went away.

Comment: Worked perfectly on 5.0.1, Saved me mucking round with all my provisioning files which is what I was just about to do.

Comment: Worked for me, tried all the other ones, none but restarting the device (iPad in my case) did the trick.

Comment: Works fine. but anyone know why this happens??

Comment: If your device is jailbroken, just respring. Happened to me while launching two different targets with the same bundle identifier one after the other.

Answer (score 33):

Most annoying bug.
Only solution at this point:

If you're trying to run on a device: Shut off and restart device

If you're trying to run in simulator on Mac: restart your Mac

You can also do a Force Quit on the process via the Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 9):

I've run into that with the simulator and the only solution I've found is to reboot the computer running Xcode.

Answer (score 6):

kill all Simulator processes, that can cause this error as well.
using following terminal command

```
kill -9 `ps ax | grep Simulator | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442/bootstrap-server)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen with the LLDB debugger when an app is paused at a breakpoint and the app is run again from xcode. The result is a zombie process on either the device or the development machine (when debugging in the simulator).

Only way to resolve seems to be a restart of the iDevice or the machine running the simulator.

Stopping the app completely before running it again in the debugger appears to prevent the problem from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by deleting my device form the Xcode 4.4 Organizer:

1. disconnect your device from your computer.
2. in Xcode: Window => Organizer
3. Choose the first tab ("Devices") from the top panel
4. Right click your device from the list at the left side of the Organizer, and choose "remove from organizer"