# Couldn't register [...] with the bootstrap server

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, bootstrapping

I keep getting this error when launching my app on the iOS Simulator:

```
Couldn't register com.mycompany.MyApp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.
```

I've read other reports of this error and it seems there is no obvious fix for it (restarting the iOS Simulator, restarting Xcode etc..)

At this point here's a list of things I've tried:

- Restarting the Simulator
- Restarting Xcode
- Rebooting my machine
- Deleting my app's Derived Data, and Cleaning
- Deleting the iOS Simulator App Support directory
- Reverting to a 2 weeks old version of the app (which was working 2 weeks ago)
- Deleting the application in the Simulator (by clicking-holding on it and hitting the X button)
- Upgrading Xcode form 4.1 to 4.2, and running the app both in iOS Simulator 4.3 and 5.0

Nothing worked, I still get the same bootstrap error.. Any (and at this point I really do mean ANY) suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit: Just wanted to add that the app runs fine on a device. I only get this error on the simulator...

Comment: You could try changing your bundle id, product name and so on in the plist.

Comment: Just tried, didn't help... this is really baffling.. guess I'll have to keep testing on the device.

Comment: A few suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442/bootstrap-server

Comment: Same problem here. No "solutions" do anything at all. The crash is exactly the same on an iPad, so it's not a weird Simulator bug.

Comment: I think this is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442/bootstrap-server

Comment: if you're experiencing this on Jenkins with a CI build then most likely something is wrong with the scheme setup for unit tests.

Answer (score 13):

As the GDB said:

> This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger

So find out it and kill it. ;)
I restarted the mac, and it run successfully.

---

**Tip**: Well, this may be not work sometimes, so I strongly suggest that you press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to make sure that you do have stopped the simulator (or device). I find that in most cases the simulator (or device) will not stop exactly when it crashes. I rarely met this issue again with pressing the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> every time it crashes or even just normal exit. Hope this will be helpful. :)

Comment: or just reset your iphone if you are deploying the app on the device

Comment: Ya! I met this situation & reboot it.

Comment: By the way, to avoid it, just make sure you turned off the simulator(cmd+.), whenever you want to rebuild the code. ;)

Comment: Restarting the mac is not really a useful solution :P

Comment: It seems @silvertab had tried it already. But anyway, I solved my issue in this way finally. :D

Comment: @Sarah keep in mind to use `cmd`+`.` to stop the task first every time ;)

Comment: I've had this quite a few times, the only thing that works for me is restarting my Mac - which is annoying but works everytime.

Comment: @TheBestBigAl you can try to press `cmd`+`.` to make sure that you do have stopped the simulator. I find that in most cases the simulator will not stop exactly when it crashes. I rarely met this issue again with pressing the `cmd`+`.` every time it crashes or even just normal exit. :)

Comment: It works well on my simulator but throws the error everytime I run on the device. Restarting mac didnt help!

Comment: Hi @Dexter, please have a look at the edited answer, hope that will be helpful to you. At least I solved this issue by this way. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Kjuly.. My problem was solved by restarting iPad and restarting xcode. Next time, will try the new solution :)

Answer (score 11):

I just closed my xcode & restart my device(ipad2) and it works for me :)
You can try this :: [Couldn't register with the bootstrap Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442/bootstrap-server)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, go to clear the memory of the iphone simulator
Simulator > recovery content and setting
then run the program again.

Answer (score 1):

i just change the identifier and the app can work again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too and I noticed that it works for me if you close the simulator and stop the program and then change your company name.

I don't know why but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my bundle identifier finally

No matter you reboot all devices and cleanup all , it gets stuck hard in the debugger..

don't know how to clear it..

Answer (score 1):

As I experienced, device (or simulator) restart does solve the issue,
BUT it would be better not to couse it.

Also my experience is that: 
You can find the place of crash by cousing it. In such time developers usually press "STOP the running scheme" this could cause zombie process stuck in device.
BUT 
if you press "COUNTINUE program execution", debugger will terminate the process, it will not become a zombie.

Answer (score 0):

I opened Activity Monitor and searched for my app name, and found another instance of it listed. I used Activity Monitor to quit that instance, and the problem went away for me.