# iOS App runs on simulator but not device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash, ios5

My application has no errors, warnings or memory leaks, runs flawlessly on the simulator, but black screens on my iPhone 4 running with iOS 5.  The `SIGABRT`'s happens in main on this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Since my code seems ok, does anyone know what kind of things in general can cause this kind of behavior?

Where else can I look for possible errors?  All the references to this `SIGABRT` I'm getting are in assembly... 0.o

**EDIT:**
Output from the debugger:

```
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-4281-83
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
Couldn't register BearNun.Stack-Meet-App with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(gdb)
```

Not sure where another process would be running...I deleted the app from the iPhone, cleaned my project, and then ran it again (once the stop button was greyed out, I thought that meant that no processes in the program were running).

Comment: There's no such thing as an iPhone emulator. What you're referring to is the iOS *Simulator*, which is rather different from an emulator (to wit, if it was an emulator then it would behave identically to the device (barring bugs)).

Comment: Can you add a complete backtrace of where the crash occurs? Just type `bt` in the debugger console and paste the output here.

Comment: Hey, added the debugger output in an edit in the original post since here wasn't enough space.

Answer (score 10):

I think you have problem with case-sensitive.
The iOS simulator isn't case-sensitive while the device is! I suggest if you work with some files or something like that, check your address and try again.

I hope it be useful for you!

Comment: Yikes!  Thanks for the tip - it's a great one!  Let the case-combing begin!

Comment: Thanks for the replies - my problem is looking like another in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator

Comment: Oh "Couldn't register" error, I had same problem before and I found solution on this thread, perhaps this thread works for you (http://stackoverflow.com/q/7853136/893863)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  I had to completely power down my device and restart it and then it started working fine. Also had restarted Xcode.