# Debugging on iPad for a trigger.io app

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, trigger.io

I'm working on an app for iPad using [trigger.io](https://trigger.io/). The app build find and runs in the emulator. It also builds successfully to an ipa which I can install on my iPad via [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/).

When I try `forge run ios` with `"device": "device"` in `local_config.json` it copies everything to the device and then gives the following error:

```
[100%] Installed package /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app/
------ Debug phase ------
Assertion failed: (AMDeviceStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), &gdbfd, NULL) == 0), function start_remote_debug_server, file fruitstrap.c, line 231.

[  ERROR] See /[path]/forge-error.log for more details
[  ERROR] Please contact support@trigger.io
```

The `forge-error.log` file doesn't exist.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

OSX Lion, XCode 4.1, iPad 2, iOS 5.1.1

**Update:**

Updated to XCode 4.4.1 and it's getting a bit further. Here's the new error:

```
[100%] Installed package /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app/
------ Debug phase ------
[100%] Connecting to remote debug server
-------------------------
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
[New thread 7171]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
0x2fe51028 in ?? ()
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done

[  ERROR] See /[path]/forge-error.log for more details
```

Any ideas?

**Further Update:**

The same problem occurs when I try and run the [Forge bootstrap](https://github.com/trigger-corp/Forge-Bootstrap) app on the iPad so I presume it's nothing to do with my code...

**And another update!**

Just noticed that it seems to error twice while the command is running. Providing a more complete output below incase it helps:

```
$ forge run ios
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.11
[   INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
[   INFO] JavaScript check complete
[   INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[   INFO] Configuration settings check complete
[   INFO] Running on iOS device: device
[   INFO] Plist OK
[   INFO] Installing app on device: is it connected?
[   INFO] ------ Install phase ------
[   INFO] [....] Waiting up to 10 seconds for iOS device to be connected
[   INFO] [  0%] Found device (fe29da73fa45e10dfb3ca8cabd215c10de079137), beginning install
[   INFO] [  5%] Copying /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app/ to device
<snip>
[   INFO] [ 49%] Copying /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app//tabs_modalWebViewController.nib to device
[   INFO] [ 50%] TakingInstallLock
[   INFO] [ 52%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[   INFO] [ 57%] ExtractingPackage
[   INFO] [ 60%] InspectingPackage
[   INFO] [ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[   INFO] [ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[   INFO] [ 70%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[   INFO] [ 80%] InstallingApplication
[   INFO] [ 85%] PostflightingApplication
[   INFO] [ 90%] SandboxingApplication
[   INFO] [100%] Installed package /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app/
[   INFO] ------ Debug phase ------
[   INFO] [100%] Connecting to remote debug server
[   INFO] -------------------------
[   INFO] Switching to remote-macosx protocol
[   INFO] [New thread 7171]
[   INFO] [Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[   INFO] 0x2fe11028 in ?? ()
[   INFO] Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
[  ERROR] Something went wrong that we didn't expect:
[  ERROR] Failed when running /[path]/.lib/fruitstrap: ------ Install phase ------
[....] Waiting up to 10 seconds for iOS device to be connected
[  0%] Found device (fe29da73fa45e10dfb3ca8cabd215c10de079137), beginning install
[  5%] Copying /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app/ to device
<snip>
[ 49%] Copying /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app//tabs_modalWebViewController.nib to device
[ 50%] TakingInstallLock
[ 52%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[ 57%] ExtractingPackage
[ 60%] InspectingPackage
[ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[ 70%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[ 80%] InstallingApplication
[ 85%] PostflightingApplication
[ 90%] SandboxingApplication
[100%] Installed package /[path]/development/ios/device-ios.app/
------ Debug phase ------
[100%] Connecting to remote debug server
-------------------------
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
[New thread 7171]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
0x2fe11028 in ?? ()
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done

[  ERROR] See /[path]/forge-error.log for more details
[  ERROR] Please contact support@trigger.io
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart the phone and the computer.

I found the solution here:
[iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)

Edit: I had this problem once more, mostly it's a result of wrong certificate or provisioning profile. Please see [iOS App runs on simulator but not device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192108/ios-app-runs-on-simulator-but-not-device).

Comment: No joy. The computer and simulator have been restarted multiple times and I still get the same errors...

Answer (score 0):

Try freeing space on your device, and restart it afterwards just in case. Solved it for me.