# Couldn't register "Application" with the bootstrap server

Tags: debugging, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Couldn't register […] with the bootstrap server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853136/couldnt-register-with-the-bootstrap-server)

I have multiple copies of the application with the same name but some changes in the code. When I try to run the older application I get an Error saying:

> Couldn't register "com.rvce.Page-L" with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853136/couldnt-register-with-the-bootstrap-server
may help

Comment: @StanSieler Impressive, I wouldn't have found that.