# getting error when installing the app in the device

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve developed an iphone application.i was able to install the application and was working properly.in the past two hours i m getting error while installing the application in the device.i tried restarting my device and mac but its in vain..could u guys help me out.

below is the error

Couldn't register com.upspl.bigbapp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to restart your Mac or kill the Debugger? You can also try to press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to stop the process.

For other references, take a look at similar posts:

- [iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)
- [Couldn't register […] with the bootstrap server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853136/couldnt-register-with-the-bootstrap-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try: delete your application from device and iTunes, restart your device, and then relaunch it.