# Xcode Debugging process can only be killed by rebooting Mac OS

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

Sometimes Xcode does not stop the debugging process properly and the only way to kill that process seems to be a reboot of the mac. 
I can not kill it via shell command (kill -9, or actually sudo - kill  -9). I also tried to remove the process from the launchctl table before killing with the command, which also does not work, the command returns 'No such process'.

Is there really no other way than rebooting the system in such a case??

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the process returned by `ps -ef | grep gdb` that you're trying to kill?  I did a `kill -9 this_pid` and it stopped the debugging process just fine.  The process ID is the first of the two IDs returned from `ps`.

Comment: Hi Jon, no I always tried looking up my own app with grep: ps -ef | grep Abiliator and then tried to kill that process... will try your grep next time I get debug hang and actually makes sense that I have to kill the debugger process rather then my app. Thanks.

Comment: Happening for me on M1 mac mini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking here: [Couldn't register with the bootstrap Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442/bootstrap-server) and here: [iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)

I myself experienced this occasionally, but I've never managed to resolve it using any of the methods stated. Hate to say this, but I always end up restarting the Mac to fix it.

Comment: Just experienced another hang of the debugger yesterday and there was no gdb process at that time. So again, rebooting my Mac was the only solution.

Comment: Has anyone found any fixes for this.  I am having to restart every 20 minutes with this issue

Comment: Apparently Xcode 4.3.1 fixes this. I haven't been experiencing this for some time now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment XCool. Will install the update as soon as I am live with my app and hope that then this reboots will finally have an end.

Comment: Unfortunately Apple still did not fix that. At least not properly. I still have to re-boot my laptop sometimes to get rid of these zombies. Not really happy and hope they fix that in the near future.

Comment: I've seen this with iOS before, but I'm now seeing something similar with OSX apps. I've been working on 2 completely different OSX projects and have un-killable processes still running for both of these Apps. Xcode 4.6 - is this an iOS feature finally brought to the Mac?