# Couldn't register com.xxx.appname with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.Program received signal: “SIGABRT”

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting this error while running in device.

```
Couldn't register com.xxxx.appname with the bootstrap server.
Error: unknown error code. 
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Now i rectified this problem .I have posted answer also if anyone got this error follow my post..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3375442/422353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Deleteing the app, restarting Xcode, clean build, didn't do anything

--> restart your computer

--> restart the phone
```