# Error: unknown error code. this process was already running or is hung in the debugger

Tags: xcode4.2

i know that this question has been posted a lot of times but the suggested solutions doesn't fit my case, when i try to build and run my app on the simulator, i got this error and it crashes:

```
Couldn't register test.My-App-Name with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.
```

I tried to create a new app with Xcode with the same name but i got the same issue. 
However, when i try to make a different app(different name) in Xcode, it run pretty good.

Does any one know how to solve that problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be the result of a "hung" instance of an app running within the iOS simulator itself. Have you tried resetting the contents and settings of the simulator?

Comment: Please, what does it mean Hung instance? thanx in advance.

Comment: Nothing technical -- a previous installation of the app may still be running (or have a background task running, perhaps?) within the simulator. Shutting down the simulator or resetting it via `iOS Simulator>Reset Content and Settings...` should ensure it's cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem consistently on one project. After much backtracking (basically removed all of my c++ code from the project), I found one thing that helped: I had a subfolder inside the main folder of the project, with the same name as the project:

-MyProject (folder)
--myfile.h
--myfile.mm
--MyProject (folder)
---myotherfile.h
---myotherfile.cpp

I changed the subfolder's name (which contains all my c++) to MyProjectBlaah and now the error has gone away. Restarting the simulator, Xcode, and Mac didn't help.