# Xcode 4.4: another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios5.1, xcode4.4

I have seen this similar question on SO in a few places but all of them are related to Simulator and old Xcode version. For examples, [Error: unknown error code. this process was already running or is hung in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432707/error-unknown-error-code-this-process-was-already-running-or-is-hung-in-the-de) and [Error when testing on iOS simulator: Couldn't register with the bootstrap server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)

I have never seen this error before until I upgraded my Xcode to 4.4. ***It works fine on the simulator but not on an iPhone.*** I have also upgraded Xcode to 4.4.1 today but no luck. How to get rid of this error on an iPhone?

> Couldn't register com.mycompany.myapp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restart both Xcode and iDevice.

Comment: And remember not to set or remove any breakpoints during a debugging run - yeah I know right, because who would want to do that?! (Xcode 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if restarting xcode doesn't work, restart your MAC & restart your iPhone - it worked even in xCode 4.3. In xCode 4.4 it seems to happen less often.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that restarting is not required anymore with Xcode 4.4

Just close and restart. If the normal closing won't work press ctrl+alt+esc and exit xcode immediately.

Unfortunately there is no other way to prevent this (expect if you are hammering on run ;) )

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/solving-simulator-bootstrap-errors.html) on fixing the bootstrap errors.