# Developing iOS/Xcode/PhoneGap app; randomly receive SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I was developing an app in Xcode and everything was working just fine.  I went to shut off my network on my Mac to try and simulate 'No Network' so I could test a setting I had just set using the Phonegap.js.

I suddenly got a `SIGABRT` notice and can no longer run the app on my iOS simulator.  It builds just fine. This has happened to me before under different circumstances.

I have found that all I have to do is paste the same code into a new project and all is well. So it appears to not be a code issue.

I've researched it and found that many people around the web are reporting it but I could not find where anyone successfully fixed it.

That is why I was hoping that someone on StackOverflow might have seen this before and know how to fix it.

I did come across a suggestion to remove a line our of your plist info file but that was for an iPad target and I am targetting the iPhone (but I still tried it and it didn't work either way).

---

XCODE 4.2, PhoneGap 1.3.0, iPhone 5.0

Comment: Have you tried a clean build after one of these random `SIGABRT` happens?

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned and built.  It always cleans and builds just fine.

Comment: To get better help, you should add Xcode, iOS, and PhoneGap versions and related info to the question. Right now there really isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator  --This thread describes my issue perfectly and offers several solutions (nice to know I'm NOT crazy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am about 99% convinced that it has to do with a bug in XCode and ARC.