# Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

My project was running with out any problems. But suddenly it began to show crash with an error "Couldn't register com.yourcompany.iconnector with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger" in debug mode

I tried restarting system, simulator and xcode but still the issue exist. Any one please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator) question and answer thread, it has a lot of info on the matter.

Also, try a 'Reset Content and Settings' for the Simulator.

Comment: Thanks Madumal it is solved. But is there any way for not happening again

Comment: I dont think there's any of of ensuring that'll never happen buddy, it seems to be a sort of bug in XCode and the Simulator mostly. But, everytime it happened to me, a quick Reset of the Simulator, Clean and Build from XCode and at worst a a Mac restart usually fixes the problem.

Comment: No problemo. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 4):

I know your specific problem was with the simulator, but sometimes I get the same error when using a real device.  It usually occurs when the debugger is attached and I build and run again.

To avoid the debugger hanging - when you set a breakpoint and the debugger pauses execution, make sure you continue execution before building and running again.

To solve the debugger hanging error, just restart the device and build and run again.

Answer (score -4):

Whenever you have a problem like unknown error code or "Couldn't register com.yourcompany.iconnector with the bootstrap server.

Restart your system it will be resolved.