# Error while install application in my device

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

I got error when I goes to install my application in iPhone/iPad.
Application running properly in simulator.

Error message

Couldn't register com.spaceo.pushnotificationtest with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)  and also [here](http://sugartin.info/2011/12/26/strange-error-by-ios-simulator-bootstrap-server-couldnt-register/)

Comment: I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay your device was struck in debug mode on your previous installation due to some error. You need to restart your device and clean the project in xcode to install application in your device
`This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger` This statement clearly states what was the error so restart your device and try again

Answer (score 1):

I also get this error, restarting my device solves the problem.