# When I run a simple Objective-C program, it often says something is already running

Tags: objective-c

When I run a simple Objective-C program, it often says:

> “C-Features” is already running. Click Stop to terminate and launch a new instance."

I wonder what it means.

Comment: Maybe this topic already helps you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run the app in the simulator, click STOP in Xcode. If that doesn't help, restart Xcode and the simulator and try again. The simulator is probably running another instance that hasn't been "released".