# XCode & Instruments, how to clear the list of processes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments

I'm debugging an iPad app and I'm getting a GIGANTIC list of processes to attach to when selecting the "choose target" drop down in Instruments.

It's literally showing every single process that I have run and terminated when I start and stop my app that I'm debugging.  They are listed under the Attach To Process->System section, that's where my IOS apps to debug always show up, but they never get removed, so I have to dig through hundreds of entries.

I've tried restarting xcode, instruments and IOS simulator... Is there any way to clear this without restarting my mac?  I'd hate to have to do that every time.

Comment: Not sure why you have to do that way? why can't you simply do in xcode menu by choosing Product->Profile. You can also do this by long pressing the play button to get a popup menu and choose 'Profile'

Comment: This problem is fixed in Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zombie Processes from iPhone Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812064/zombie-processes-from-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you exit your app in the iOS simulator, it creates what is called a "Zombie Process". To this date, the only way you can clear these processes is by rebooting your mac.

Also, when you want to choose  a target for your Instruments application, the process you will want to select will most likely be the highest-numbered process for the app you are currently testing.

Here is a stackoverflow reference regarding the zombie processes left behind by XCode: [Xcode leaving zombie processes after running iOS tests/simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209743/xcode-leaving-zombie-processes-after-running-ios-tests-simulator)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I figured this would be the problem.  Also, in theory, it being the highest number and easiest to find is true, but unfortunately I haven't rebooted my mac in MONTHS so the PID has rolled over a few times now.