# iPhone 6.1 simulator leaves zombie process that can not be killed！

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I debugged my app using the xcode's iPhone 6.1 simulator.
After I stop my app using the xcode's stop button, I found there always some dummy process that still could be seen using "ps ux" command. For example, I runed a app called "IAPNoob", when the app is running on the simulator, I could see a process:

```
Chandler   781   0.0  0.5   875156  20332   ??  SX   11:26上午   0:00.33
/Users/Chandler/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/
29FAE7CA-3C0E-4B52-A916-572FEF640A76/IAPNoob.app/IAPNoob
```

When I stopped the app using xcode's stop button, the process turned to:

```
Chandler   781   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z    11:26上午   0:00.00 (IAPNoob)
```

Time and time, this kind of dummy process will caused my system to be nasty slow.
I tried to kill the process, using kill -9, but it does not work.
Can any one tell me how to solve the problem?

ps:I tried to quit the simulator, but this could not kill the zombie process.

pps: I tried another method to quit my app by double clicking the "home" button on the simulator and kill the app, however, it still leaves the zombie process

Comment: Can you quit the Simulator?

Comment: Yes, I have tried so, but the zombie processes were still there. You can tried it yourself.

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 4.6.3.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17117132/77567).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zombie Processes from iPhone Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812064/zombie-processes-from-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that when this happens, you restart the computer. That's what I do when Xcode has made things slow.

Also, file a bug with Apple if you think this is a problem!

Personally, I don't believe it is a problem. It's a zombie. That means it's not doing anything. It has terminated. It cannot "slow" your computer. It isn't using any computer resources. [See, for example:](http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/UNIX_Concepts/concepts.zombies.txt)

> A zombie or defunct process is the death certificate of a process that has already terminated. The only system resource being consumed by it is the process block used to store its termination status

So don't worry, be happy.

Comment: It is phenomenon reappear every time when I stop the app using xcode. Do you have the same problem? My simulator is 6.1

Comment: Are you asking: Does my computer become slow every time I stop an app in the Simulator using Xcode? No, it doesn't.

Comment: Did you find the zombie process after you stop the app using xcode?

Comment: Yes but I don't care and I don't think you should care either.

Comment: After a couple of weeks of intensive iOS development, I filled up my process table with zombies. Xcode wouldn't work because it couldn't fork clang any more. I *had* to reboot then. (I know that it's possible to up the PID table size, but it's still clearly a nuisance -- and the limit isn't infinite for a reason, right?)

Answer (score 0):

In activity monitor force quit the simulator

Comment: I have tried this, it can not kill the zombie process.BTW:you can not seen the zombie process using "activity monitor", you can only find it using ps command

Comment: Do you mean the command exit in the command line? That will only logout the terminal instead of terminating the app I am debugging