# Simulator not working - null alert when on finished running app on iphone 5s simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm new to Xcode. Recently has just downloaded the Xcode6-beta2 to learn swift and followed tutorial online to setup app to run on real device.

My simulator on Xcode6-beta2 was working before but it's not longer working after the setup to run app on real device.

There is no problem when run my app on real device but when i try with simulator(iphone5s). The simulator never open & on finishing running app on simulator it trigger me with an "null" alert.

I didn't notice any other error on console except the alert(null).

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Below link for screenshot of the null alert error:

> http://i61.tinypic.com/2a976zl.jpg

Comment: Where does the null alert originate from? The simulator? Xcode? Have you checked if the simulator process is still running and killed that? Other things to try: Clean the project, delete the derived data, restart xcode ;)

Comment: The null alert originate from the Xcode and it appear after the build succeeded message. I has quit my simulator. Clean the project and delete the derived date from ~/Library/Developer/xcode/ then close and restart the Xcode. Unfortunately the same problem still appear.

Comment: Try to list all zombie processes `ps -el | grep 'Z'`. If your app is there you may need to restart the Mac.

Comment: Restart Mac has solve the problem. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Great, I added a summary of our chat here as an answer so you can accept that if you want to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the comments:
Your simulator process is probably still around as a zombie process. You can check with

```
ps -el | grep 'Z'
```

If that's the case a restart of your mac should help.
More information in this question: [iPhone - strange error when testing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator)